# A question about positive operator pregenerator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Thank you for reading.

My question was raised up when I tried to prove an example in the book of Liggett(1985), which is in P13 Example 2.3(a).

Here is a link of the page:

https://books.google.com/books?id=7JbqBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR3&dq=liggett%201985&hl=zh-CN&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q=liggett%201985&f=false

My questions are as follows:

1) what the definition of positive operator is while the book didn't mention that there is a Hilbert space;

2) how to prove Example 2.3 (a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not research level and would be better suited on MathStackExchange.

Positivity here just means $f\ge 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $Tf\ge 0$ (where $f\ge 0$ is defined as $f(x)\ge 0$ for each $x\in X$).

The example is verified using Proposition 2.2: If $f(\eta)=\min f(X)$ then $g=f-f(\eta)1\ge 0$ and since $T(1)=1$ we get
$$ (T-I)(f)(\eta)=T(f)(\eta)-f(\eta)=T(f-f(\eta)1)(\eta)\ge 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! I am sorry that this is really not research level. Is it appropriate to delete this post? However, I think this may be disrespectful of the time you spend.